# getting "Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat/Observable'" but only code requiring it is RXjs itself

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, rxjs, rxjs6

error I am getting in console when running an 'ng serve':

```
module.js:550
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat/Observable'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\[USR]\source\repos\[ProprietaryApp]\web\node_modules\rxjs\Observable.js:6:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
```

Problem:  All of my code is updated and using the new reference locations.  Here is an example:

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
```

I did a search in VSCode of all places that use 'rxjs-compat/Observable' and I found that every single one of them is in node_modules\rxjs or a subfolder of node_modules\rxjs.

[image: RXjsLocations]

does RXjs V6 **require**  the compat file?  I dont want to use it.  The compat file is supposed to be a **temporary** fix.

Comment: What version of angular? Did you recently upgrade? I wonder if a fresh install of dependencies would help (delete node_modules & package-lock.json, npm install).

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are using older version (5 or lower) of RxJs. Try installing Rxjs Compat in order to have all imports fixed implicitly:

`npm install --save rxjs-compat`

Otherwise, you need to change all imports explicitly.